# image in h3 overlay h3 border

Tags: html, css

I have something like this

```
<h3 style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
<strong>Some text</strong><img src="someimg.png">
</h3>
```

And it's look like this:

[image]

And I want to get this:

[image]

Anyone know how? Thanks in advance for your answers.

This is my html 
`<h3 style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
    <strong><span style="font-size:20px;">Spam</span></strong> <img style="width: 50px; height: 50px; float: right;" src="spam.fw.png" alt="">
</h3>`

that's about it for css and html

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: Did you try adding padding to your image?

Comment: Actually I didn't try to add padding to img...I'll try it right now..

Comment: Do you have a link to the particular image you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hCQuH/

```
img
{
    margin-right:-15%;
}
h3
{
width:85%
}
```

Comment: Actually this is solution!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could try adding a `background-color` to the image (that orange color), which should cover up the underlying border.

**EDIT**: It's hard to know for certain what will work without seeing the CSS you have already...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your img class
`position: absolute;
    right: -10px;top:30px;`

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YAfKS/4/

Answer (score -1):

This should solve it. 
CSS

```
img
{
float:right;
padding:0px 2px;
background:white;
}
```

Then add relative positioning to get the desired result.

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Es2Ay/

Comment: fiddle is empty, but I like the idea